# ASIHttpRequest: Can someone see the URL being sent?

Tags: ios, sql-server, asihttprequest

I'm using ASIHttpRequest to send data back and forth to the server in my **IOS** game.

I'm wondering if someone can see the url being send to the server, someway?
... If that's the case, cheating is possible.

thanks in advance

The request looks like this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://xx.xxx.xx.x/development/"];

__block ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL: url]; 
__weak ASIHTTPRequest *request_b = request;

[request setDelegate: self]; 
[request setQueue: [[DatabaseHelper sharedInstance] networkQue]]; 
[request setShouldContinueWhenAppEntersBackground: NO]; 
[request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"text/html; charset=utf-8;"];
[request setDefaultResponseEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
[request setTimeOutSeconds: 20.0f]; 
[request setCachePolicy: ASIDoNotWriteToCacheCachePolicy | ASIDoNotReadFromCacheCachePolicy]; 

[request setPostValue:@"aSecretString" forKey:@"secret"]; 
[request setPostValue: @"updateUser" forKey:@"apiToRun"]; 
[request setPostValue: @"4" forKey:@"userId"];
```

url:

```
http://xx.xxx.xx.x/development/secret=aSecretString&apiToRun=updateUser&userId=4
```

Comment: Im trying to answer the question you just deleted....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a GET request, data is sent as part of the URL and is easy to intercept with HTTP monitoring. If you use POST, this information will not be visible in the URL.